Is TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT equivalent to ALL_COMMANDS_BIT?
In the Vulkan documentation TOP_OF_PIPE and BOTTOM_OF_PIPE are deprecated, and says that you should change:
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT in second synchronization scope

// From
  .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;

// To
  .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT_KHR;
  .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_2_NONE_KHR;

So, apparently, ALL_COMMANDS_BIT and TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT are equivalent? I thought TOP_OF_PIPE and BOTTOM_OF_PIPE referred to the graphics pipeline, whereas ALL_COMMANDS_BIT referred to all stages, including the ones that aren't part of the graphics pipeline, TRANSFER and COMPUTE.

I believe that TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT is equivalent to ALL_COMMANDS only if used in second synchronization scope. If you use TOP_OF_PIPE in first synchronization scope, it means that the execution as continue as soon as top of the pipe is reached, which is before vertex, fragment and other steps.
So in first synchronization scope, ALL_COMMANDS is equivalent to BOTTOM_OF_PIPE and in second synchronization scope, ALL_COMMANDS is equivalent to TOP_OF_PIPE.
Feel free to correct me if needed.
